# VS-2012 : Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am not being able to debug the code for a MVC4 application in VS-2012. The same code was running fine a few days back. Error as below:
Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols  have been loaded for this document.

I have tried below possible ways:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the solution.
- Setting 'Just my code' to false and true both.
- Repaired VS.
- Cleared the bin and obj folders also related GAC and temp asp.net folder.
- Checked in Debug->Windows->Modules, it gives 'Can not find or open PDB file', when tried to load manually, it can't find the pdb file though file is present in the mentioned location.
- Checked that code is building in Debug mode with no optimization and Debug set to true in web.config file as well.
- The problem persists even if I create a new project in VS.
- Also tried reverting all the changes and took the latest version from TFS.

Any help on this is highly appreciated as I have gone through many threads but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried running VS in administrator mode?

Comment: Are you connecting to the right process for debugging? localhost vs. IIS?

Comment: Try using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` .before the line where you want to break.

Comment: @Amitd in Debug->Windows->Modules I have noticed under User Code column VS mentions 'No', ie. its not treating my code as user code and hence not loading symbols neither automatically nor manually. Any clue why? Also, is there a chance that some thing in VS is corrupted and re-installation is the last resort?

Comment: I doubt  that could have happened. Its a possibility . Does it work with console applications. Create a small console app or new mvc app, but a break point and does that breakpoint get hit?

Comment: @Amitd I have already tried creating new projects and it doesn't work. That's the reason I am suspecting the issue is not related to any specific project but it's related to VS. Please suggest if there is any other idea, I am still stuck.

Comment: @manshuan try cleanly uninstalling http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2013/10/15/how-to-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-visual-studio-2012/  and then reinstall . Or you can install the latest version of VS  ie. 2017

Answer (score 0):

Try exiting the IIS express, which will enforce visual studio to relaunch IIS express and load symbols.

Answer (score 0):

One change did the trick for me, though not sure what exactly fixed it. Couple of projects were hosted in IIS. I deleted all the hosted sites form IIS, configured them again and that worked for me. However, still not sure what exactly was wrong in IIS but yeah, it was IIS.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to open the solution as administrator, right click on the web project--> properties -->Web--> IIS express--> project URL same as in your iis, create virtual directory. save, build, rebuild, publish, run.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is to enter the project properties (right click on the project in Project Explorer), Click the "Build" tab, Click "Advanced" in the lower right corner and choose an Output other then "None" (for example PDB-only). This should generate the necessary PDB file.

[image: Advanced Build Settings]